# Server Side Blazor, can't get screen to update

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

In the standard WeatherForecastService I added a delay to simulate slow data loading:

```
  public Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync(DateTime startDate)
  {
      var rng = new Random();
      Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
      return Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
      {
          Date = startDate.AddDays(index), TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
          Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
      }).ToArray());
  }
```

In the FetchData.razor, I added a conditional spinner and a button to fetch the data:

```
<h1>Weather forecast</h1>
@if (loading)
{
    <div class="spinner-border">Loading</div>
}
@if (forecasts == null)
{
    <button @onclick="@loadthem">Load them</button>
}
else
   //render results

@code {
  private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;
  private bool loading = false;

  private async Task loadthem()
  {
    loading = true;
    this.StateHasChanged();

    forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    loading = false;
  }
}
```

The purpose was to get a spinner during the data load. This does not work. In other answers here on SO, I've seen suggestions to use :

```
InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
```

instead of:

```
this.StateHasChanged();
```

but this seems to make no difference. Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this spinner showing while data loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've called your method `GetForecastAsync`, but you haven't declared it as an `async Task`.  I'm surprised you're not getting an Intellisense warning message or error when you try to `await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);`  at all.  Also, I recommend using `await Task.Delay(5000);`

Comment: Thank you! It seems I was temporarily blind

Comment: . . . said every programmer at least 10 times a week! :D